# "Unexpected token import" implementing native ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I need to refactor some JavaScript code and am trying to implement ES6 modules using the native import/export commands.  I struggled for awhile to get this working, so I am going to document what needed done here for future reference.

The symptom is that I receive the following message in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

My basic code for testing is:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Import test</h1>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript" src="./import.js"></script>
</html>
```

import.js:

```
import { apath } from './alert_path';
```

alert_path.js:

```
export function apath() {
    alert('Bang!!!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two actions I had to take to resolve this problem.

First, Chrome must be at 61+ or chrome://flags must enable Experimental Web Platform features.

Second, the script tag must use type module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Import test</h1>
</body>
<script type="module" src="./import.js"></script>
</html>
```

I found the second answer [here](https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7) under What are the basics?

> Modules must be eventually included in your HTML with type="module",
>   which can appear as an inline or external script tag.

OBTW, the sample will fail due to CORS violations after this is resolved unless it is run through a server but that is another question.

Comment: Yes, the support of ES6 modules is very low atm.  You can polyfill using something like system.js,, -> https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs